# TimeoutException: Message: on random runs on web scrapping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to scrape the product description of every product from the search results.  The search results are in 50 pages with 60 products per page. So, in total I need to scrape 3000 products. With the code I currently have, this error comes up on random runs:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/hj/yrd6ng651fv5d2_gtngcysy40000gn/T/ipykernel_50778/696262163.py in <module>
     34 for link in product_links:
     35         driver.get(link)
---> 36         WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "page-product")))
     37 
     38         driver.execute_script("""

/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:
```

Sometime the error happens after it scrapes 60 data, sometimes after 300 data, sometimes not even scrape a single data.

I tried to modified the WebDriverWait from the 10 up to 100. Still, it doesn't fix the issue.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options       # to customize chrome display
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from time import sleep
from collections import Counter
import json
from turtle import delay
import time
import pandas as pd

# create object for chrome options
chrome_options = Options()

# Customize chrome display
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1365,6572.610")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')      

# create webdriver object
path = '/Applications/chromedriver'
webdriver_service = Service(path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=chrome_options)

baseurl = 'https://shopee.co.id'

product_links = []

for page in range(5, 11):
    search_link = 'https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=obat%20kanker&page={}'.format(page)
    driver.get(search_link)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 80).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "shopee-search-item-result")))

    driver.execute_script("""
            var scroll = document.body.scrollHeight / 10;
            var i = 0;
            function scrollit(i) {
            window.scrollBy({top: scroll, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
            i++;
            if (i < 10) {
                setTimeout(scrollit, 500, i);
                }
            }
            scrollit(i);
            """)
    sleep(5)
    html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    product_list = soup.find_all('div',class_='col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item' )
    for item in product_list:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
            product_links.append(baseurl + link['href'])

#testlink = 'https://shopee.co.id/Obat-Herbal-Kanker-Payudara-Serviks-Hati-Usus-Prostat-Leukimia-dan-Paru-Paru-ORIGINAL-100-ASLI-i.166801435.2584201334?sp_atk=70c736d4-ed07-435c-8edd-4e6e7552a91d&xptdk=70c736d4-ed07-435c-8edd-4e6e7552a91d'

herbcancerlist = []
for link in product_links:
        driver.get(link)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "page-product")))

        driver.execute_script("""
                var scroll = document.body.scrollHeight / 10;
                var i = 0;
                function scrollit(i) {
                window.scrollBy({top: scroll, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
                i++;
                if (i < 10) {
                setTimeout(scrollit, 500, i);
                }
                }
                scrollit(i);
                """)

        sleep(10)
        html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

        try:
                name = soup.find('div', class_='_2rQP1z').get_text()
                price = soup.find('div', class_='_2Shl1j').get_text() 
                sold = soup.find('div', class_ = 'HmRxgn').get_text() 
                rate = soup.find('div', class_ = '_3y5XOB _14izon').get_text() 
                city = soup.find('span', class_ = '_2fJrvA').get_text() 
                specification = soup.find('div', class_ = '_2jz573').get_text()          
        except:
                name = 'No name'
                price = 'No price'
                sold = 'No value'
                rate = 'No rate'
                city = 'No city'
                specification = 'No spec'


        herbcancer = {
                'name': name,
                'price': price,
                'sold': sold,
                'rate': rate,
                'city': city,
                'specification': specification
                }

        herbcancerlist.append(herbcancer)
        print('Saving: ', herbcancer['name'])

df = pd.DataFrame(herbcancerlist)
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one way of getting all those products' info, put them into a dataframe, and save that dataframe to disk as a csv file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t
import json
import pandas as pd
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm 

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")
chrome_options.add_argument('--load-extension=/home/user/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/1.44.0_1')


webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

big_df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in tqdm(range(50)):
    url = f'https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=obat%20kanker&page={x}' 
    browser.get(url)
    t.sleep(5)
    items = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'script[data-rh="true"]'))) 
    for i in items:
        json_obj = json.loads(i.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
        if json_obj['@type'] == 'Product':
            big_df = pd.concat([big_df, pd.json_normalize(json_obj)], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    t.sleep(1)
print(big_df)
big_df.to_csv('medicinal_herbs_indonesian.csv')
```

Note the use of an adblocking extension, and the use of pandas/padas concat. Result printed in terminal:

```
@context    @type   name    description     url     productID   image   brand   offers.@type    offers.price    offers.priceCurrency    offers.availability     aggregateRating.@type   aggregateRating.bestRating  aggregateRating.worstRating     aggregateRating.ratingCount     aggregateRating.ratingValue     offers.lowPrice     offers.highPrice
0   http://schema.org   Product     GRAVIDA BHARATA OBAT KANKER PAYUDARA AMPUH |KANKER GANAS HERBAL TERDAFTAR DBPOM MUI WARYANTO076         https://shopee.co.id/GRAVIDA-BHARATA-OBAT-KANKER-PAYUDARA-AMPUH-KANKER-GANAS-HERBAL-TERDAFTAR-DBPOM-MUI-WARYANTO076-i.282306593.7674724221  7674724221  https://cf.shopee.co.id/file/40d3d0c5a7fc388294950b7586081843       Offer   275000.00   IDR     http://schema.org/InStock   AggregateRating     5.0     1.0     252     4.89    NaN     NaN
1   http://schema.org   Product     Walatra Zedoril 7 Asli Obat Herbal Kanker Tumor Dan Segala Jenis Benjolan Aman Tanpa Efek Samping       https://shopee.co.id/Walatra-Zedoril-7-Asli-Obat-Herbal-Kanker-Tumor-Dan-Segala-Jenis-Benjolan-Aman-Tanpa-Efek-Samping-i.189502097.3139156637   3139156637  https://cf.shopee.co.id/file/b0b7d9c09666f2fd237f3279b8194dc4   Walatra     Offer   255000.00   IDR     http://schema.org/InStock   AggregateRating     5.0     1.0     1272    4.80    NaN     NaN
2   http://schema.org   Product     Obat Herbal Kanker Payudara, Serviks, Hati, Usus, Prostat, Leukimia dan Paru Paru ORIGINAL 100% ASLI        https://shopee.co.id/Obat-Herbal-Kanker-Payudara-Serviks-Hati-Usus-Prostat-Leukimia-dan-Paru-Paru-ORIGINAL-100-ASLI-i.166801435.2584201334  2584201334  https://cf.shopee.co.id/file/1a159f810da5508ec3330ce174ca2eab       Offer   525000.00   IDR     http://schema.org/InStock   AggregateRating     5.0     1.0     1197    4.90    NaN     NaN
3   http://schema.org   Product     IDR Madu Hitam / Obat Kanker / Obat Kanker Serviks 350 gram         https://shopee.co.id/IDR-Madu-Hitam-Obat-Kanker-Obat-Kanker-Serviks-350-gram-i.12836685.4460609439  4460609439  https://cf.shopee.co.id/file/3b96e9f5fb11977b946bb5e1c4585a72   IDR     Offer   250000.00   IDR     http://schema.org/InStock   AggregateRating     5.0     1.0     6   4.83    NaN     NaN
[....]
```

Following on this logic, you can get the individual products' urls from big_df['url'], and scrape them one by one, also using that adblock extension. To make the code more redundant, you can use a database, save the big dataframe there, save the products there, use try/except blocks, mark the ones successfully scraped, retry the others.